# Xcode Change UILabel size inside Prototype cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uilabel

In an UITableView, I would like to draw a bar in each prototype cell, which has a different size in each cell to indicate the amount of a value

For the bar, I use an UILabel (tried a UIview as well, with the same result) which I want to change in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

int value = //Math to calculate value per cell
LessionViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"lessionItems"];
CGRect frmBlueLabel = cell.labelBlueBackground.frame;
frmBlueLabel.size.width = value;
cell.labelValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", value]
cell.labelBlueBackground.frame = frmBlueLabel;
return cell;
}
```

Of course cell.labelBlueBackground.frame is hooked up in IB properly. When I debug, I can see that cell.labelBlueBackground.frame has the correct value when the cell is returned.

However in my application, the size is equal in all cells.

I have the other label labelValue in that cell where I set the text attribute - that works just fine.

Is it not possible to do the resize in cellForRowAtIndexPath? How can I workaround this?

Many thanks!

Comment: That might be all right, just check `cell.labelBlueBackground` if it is nil?

Comment: Nope, it is not. As mentioned, then I po the cell.labelBlueBackground, I can see that the frame has the right size. Just when I see it in the compiled application, it does not have the new size, but just the one which I defined in IB. It looks to me that after I set the size in this method, iOS will fetch the old size from the IB.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. It looks like it's not possible to change frames during the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

After some research, I was able to solve this via the following code:

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    [self updateAllBars];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self updateAllBars];


}
```

While updateAllBars is a function I wrote that iterates through all cells and changes the frame.
Interestingly this has to be executed in viewWillAppear as well as in viewWillLayoutSubviews